# Infopath Form to show count down limit

Tags: infopath, calendar, form, limitations, counter

I have an Infopath form connected to a calendar/list that has limits the amount of times someone can submit the form according to date and time. I'm trying to find a way to display how many timeslots a specific option has left upon someone selecting to submit.

For example: In the form, if someone attempts to select the location at a specific time and there are only 10 time slots limited for that location and time, a counter will show "10 Timeslots Left". The next person who attempts to select the same date, time and location will see the counter that shows "9 Slots Left."

Is this possible?